# How do I make a command in linux using a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, gnome-terminal, manjaro

I am trying to make a command for the terminal. I have a bash script prepared (la.sh) and I want to just be able to type la to run it. How am I able to get the code so that I can just type la?

I have tried putting it in the /bin folder however had no luck.

What can I do to fix this?

I am using the latest version of Manjaro Gnome.

Thanks a lot!!!

BTW, the script was literally just `ls`.

It was just a practice script.

Comment: If you want to call it `la`, why did you call it `la.sh`?

Comment: Try adding an alias in the `.alias` or `.bashrc` files of your user. Also, if you are just simply calling the script you can rename it to `la` and add it to your user path (also in the `.bashrc` file)

Comment: Please show the script - you'll receive better advice.

Comment: The short answer is that if you want to type `la` to run a script, then write the script and save it with the name `la` in a directory on your `PATH` and make sure it is executable with `chmod +x path/to/where/you/stored/la`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets consider that your script is stored under `/some/path/la.sh`. In my opinion, you have several solutions to accomplish your goal:

**Option 1:**

Add the script to your user's path so you can directly call it.

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/some/path/" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then you will be able to use in your terminal:

```
$ la.sh
```

Using this option you can call `la.sh` with any parameters if needed. If the requirement is to call simply `la` you can also rename the script or create a softlink:

```
mv /some/path/la.sh /some/path/la
```

or

```
ln -s /some/path/la.sh /some/path/la
```

**Option 2:**

Create an alias for the script.

```
echo "alias la='/some/path/la.sh'" >> ~.bashrc
```

Then you will be able to use in your terminal:

```
$ la
```

However, using this option you will not be able to pass arguments to your script (executing something similar to `la param1 param2`) unless you define a more complex alias (an alias using a function in the `.bashrc`, but I think this is out of the scope of the question).

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Remember to reload the environment in your terminal (`source .bashrc`) or to close and open again the terminal **EVERY TIME** you make modifications to the `.bashrc` file. Otherwise, you will not be able to see any changes.

Comment: @CristianRamonCortes : I don't think option 1 fulfills the requirement, because after the `mv`, the OP can't use the original name `la.sh` again. If he had wanted the command to be available **only** as `la`, he would have created it under this name in the first place!

Comment: @user1934428 Maybe, maybe not, he didn't state that. I updated my answer using a softlink though.

Comment: He didn't say it, but I think it is logical. Who would create a program under one name, if he wants to invoke it (only) under a different name?

Answer (score 1):

The file la.sh must be placed in your [path](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/set-path-linux). Then you can create an alias for it.

```
alias la="la.sh"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a command be available under two different names (`la.sh` and `la` in your case), I recommend against using an alias: An alias defined in your .bashrc is only available in an interactive bash; If you run, say, a non-bash interactive shell, or writing a bash script, you can't use it.

The IMO most general way is to create a link. Since you said that you have already placed `la.sh` into bin, you can create the link in the same directory, i.e.

```
ln /bin/la /bin/la.sh # creates a hard link
```

or

```
ln -s /bin/la /bin/la.sh # creates a symbolic link
```

In your case, either one is fine. If you want to find out more about the differences between hard and symbolic link, look for instance [here](https://medium.com/@mirandarevans/whats-the-deal-with-hard-links-and-symbolic-links-b8bb6b2d4343).

Answer (score 0):

It worked with a mixture of everybody's answers.

All I had to do was go into the directory that `la.sh` was in.
Rename it to just `la` as a text file.
Run `chmod 777 la` to turn it into executable to anybody.
Add it to my path by using the command `export PATH=$PATH:~/Directory/It/Was/In/`

Thank you to all who contributed.